# Have questions on a tutorial I saw

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to know what is "Magic" near the getInstance(). I found it in an answer of this reply of this question ([Setting the block underneath any player to glowstone, then setting it back to the original material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271512/setting-the-block-underneath-any-player-to-glowstone-then-setting-it-back-to-th)) so I would like to know what is Magic as it isn't working and how to fix it. Magic cannot be resolved is what the error says.

```
package me.deltarift.walkonwater;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class WalkOnWater extends JavaPlugin {

    @EventHandler
    public void onStep(PlayerMoveEvent pme) {
        Player player = pme.getPlayer();
        final Block block = player.getLocation().subtract(0, 1, 0).getBlock();
        final Material type = block.getType();
        if(!type.equals(Material.GLOWSTONE)){
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Material m = player.getItemInHand().getType();
            if (m == Material.GLOWSTONE) {
                if(type.isSolid()) {
                    block.setType(Material.GLOWSTONE);
                    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(Magic.getInstance(), new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            block.setType(type);
                        }
                    },10L);
                }
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Magic is the singelton class , whose getInstance method returns the object of Magic itself.

Comment: If you don't understand a response to a question, add a comment to clarify the answer rather than creating a new question. This create unnecessary duplicates. Adding in the context of the original question also helps to improve answers for others.

Answer (score 3):

The Method `Scheduler#runTaskLater(plugin, runnable, delay)` [takes the Main class of your plugin (The one that extends JavaPlugin) as the first argument](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html#runTaskLater-org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin-org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable-long-) so that it can manage the task (i.e cancel it when the plugin is disabled)

However, a static getInstance() to get the main class is not recommended, and you should prefer to use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)as outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181026/8328871) answer.

---

Not part of the main discussion, but:

Here's some optimization tips for that code:

1. The PlayerMoveEvent is called even when the mouse is moved, i.e many, MANY times. You should have a check to make sure they're moving into another block, and that they're holding the glowstone first.
2. As of the [Combat Update](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Combat_Update), [Dual Wielding](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Dual_wield) was added, so getItemInHand() was marked deprecated. You should use `Player#getInventory().getItemInMainHand();` or `Player#getInventory().getItemInOffHand();` to get the item.
3. [As recommended by the wiki](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming#BukkitRunnable), you should use a [BukkitRunnable](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html) instead of `Scheduler#runTaskLater();`

Answer (score 0):

`Magic.getInstance()` is a static attempt to refer to a main class called `Magic` in the original user's own plugin. To use this code in your own plugin, just replace `Magic.getInstance()` with a reference to the proper instance of your own main class.

If this code is in your main class already, you can simply use `this` like so:
`Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, new Runnable(){...}`

Otherwise, you can pass your main class into the class constructor like so, where "Main" is the name of your main class:

```
Main plugin;
public class SecondaryClass {
    SecondaryClass(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
}
```

...and then refer to it like so:
`Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable(){...}`